# Query para filtrar entre fecha actual a las 3pm y fecha dia anterior a las 3PM sql

Tags: sql, date

Tengo el campo open_date y lo que requiero es hacer  una consulta que muestre todos los campos desde el día actual a las 3pm hasta el dia anterior a la misma hora, esto es en SQL

```
WHERE open_date BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD()
```

Según mi lógica debe ir de esta manera pero  no se poner los parámetros dentro de los paréntesis y no se si debo transformar a varchar.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0):

Un truco rápido para "quitar" el tiempo a la fecha actual es el siguiente:

```
select  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

-----------------------
2020-04-23 00:00:00.000
```

Obtenemos la diferencia en días desde el día 0 y el actual y sumamos esa cantidad al día 0, que en el caso de SQL Server es el `01-01-1900`. Teniendo la fecha del día, es posible ahora construir el período de tiempo restándole 9 horas para del "desde" y sumándole 15 horas para el "hasta"

```
WHERE open_date BETWEEN 
                   DATEADD(hour, -9, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
                   AND 
                   DATEADD(hour, 15, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```